# Functions that checks the greatest common divisor of composite figures in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sal_sk (int sal){ // If sal is a composite figure, then  true, if its not then false.

   for (int i = 2; i <= sal; i++){
    if(sal%i==0)
    return true;}
    return false;


}
int lkd(int a,int b){ // Checks the gcd
    int c;
    while(b > 0) {
        c = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = c;
    }
    return a;

}

int main(){
int ok;

do{
    int n;//Number of elements 
    int*a; //
    int sal;


    cout<<"Put in the number of elements"<<endl;
  std::cin >> n;
    cout<<"Input"<<n<<"elements"<<endl;
  std::cin >> *a;



int *array = new int[*a];



int rez = a[0];

for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
if(sal_sk(a[i]==true))
    rez = lkd(rez, a[i]);
delete [] array;
}
```

So i have this code and I cant see the problem why it doesnt work, can someone help me? The functions should work so it should be their fault, i think i dont understand the arrays so good so I think there is the problem. The comments will help you understand the code thanks!

Comment: `if(sal_sk(a[i]==true))` I don't think this does what you want. It employs some implicit casting which ends up turning the passed value of `a[i]` into `1` (unless `a[i]` was `0`, then it stays `0`). You probably want to remove the `==true`.

Comment: tried removing the `==true` didnt seem to help, should `cout<<` be rez?

Comment: You have to reserve memory for `a[]` (new, a vector would be better) before using it. Moreover, in `lkd`, you should check that `a > b`. If not, swap.

Comment: Of course, `sal_sk` should return a `bool`

Comment: You forgot to write the result ... How to check the program ?

Comment: You succeeded in the most difficult part, gcd calculation. You are not so far. Many little mistakes, nothing difficult. Be patient and correct them. I did not have difficulty to correct your program, but I will follow Cyber Niki's way  and let you correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even need to read all the way down to the array part to see that this program would never work.

I'll give you a clue: `sal_sk` will ALWAYS return `true`. Also, `true` and `false` are not `int`.

As far as the rest of the program is concerned, it's pretty much unsalvageable. You have an open `do` statement that leads nowhere, `main` is incomplete, the `ok` and `sal` variables are unused (???). You're trying to `cin` data into an uninitialized pointer. That `new` statement uses the wrong variable, and besides it's not where it's supposed to be. The `for` loop starts indexing from `1` which is wrong, should be `0`, and the `if` has the parentheses in the wrong place. The body of the loop itself destroys the array.

I suggest you delete the `main` function completely and start from scratch. Apart from reading a C++ book, the best suggestiong I can give you is to read your code line by line and explain to yourself what it does. If you can't, go back to the book.

A couple of hints: you don't need any `do...while` statement, you wanna initialize the array before you ask for the input, and you wanna ask for the input `n` times.